# Prices of configurable products missing in price index

Tags: configurable-product, price, index

We have a problem with the Magento store of one of our customers. The prices of all configurable products are missing in price index. Do you have any ideas how we can debug this? What we have tried so far:

- Deactivate all local and community modules
- Create new products
- Change relevant data in the backend

The Magento version is 1.9.1.0.

Comment: Hopefully an indexing expert can come along and help you debug. Can you describe the effects of this, and possibly list example data from a config & assoc simples? When you run price index (via shell) does it generate logs/reports?

Comment: The problem is that the configurable products are not shown in the product list because the collection query joins the price from the index table. Since there are no entries for configurable products the products are not included in the collection. There are not log entries or errors. Shell reindex: hp indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01